# link two check boxes to one messagebox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, checkbox, messagebox

in my form when i check both checkboxes i would like for a messagebox to displayed.
both checkboxes linked to one messagebox. i have tried different messagebox functionality but all end up displaying the messagebox when one check box is marked.

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
            checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            checkBox2.Checked = !checkBox2.Checked;

        MessageBox.Show("task completed", "form1");
```

Comment: what do you mean with "both checkboxes linked to one messagebox" ?

Comment: Did the answer below worked?

Comment: yes this helped a lot thanks for the problem solving answer Tico!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    private void cbox2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbox1.IsChecked == true && cbox2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("task completed", "form1");
        }
    }

    private void cbox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbox1.IsChecked == true && cbox2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("task completed", "form1");
        }
    }
```

Set the `if` statements at both `Checked` events of the check boxes
Not very elegant, but working.